# how to write a sqoop job using shell script and run them sequentially?

Tags: shell, jobs, sqoop

I need to run a set of sqoop jobs one after another inside a shell script. How can I achieve it? By default, it runs all the job in parallel which results in performance taking a hit. should i remove the "-m" parameter and run ?

Answer (score 0):

> -m parameter is used to run multiple map-only jobs for each sqoop command but not for all the commands that you issue.
>
> so removing -m parameter will not help you to solve the problem.

first you need to write a shell script file with your sqoop commands

```
#!/bin/bash

sqoop_command_1

sqoop_command_2

sqoop_command_3
```

save the above command with some name like sqoop_jobs.sh

then issue permissions to run on the shell file

```
chmod 777 sqoop_jobs.sh
```

now you can run/execute your shell file by issuing the following command within your terminal

```
>./sqoop_jobs.sh
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Yeah thats how i exactly do it now but the thing  is all the sqoop commands gets executed and starts running parallely.

Comment: this is the working solution that I have used earlier, here sqoop commands will be executed one after the other. Remember to provide a line break for each command and also what is the distribution that you are working on...

Comment: Did this work for you? I am facing the same problem. The sqoop commands don't run one by one.